# Recreating the iTunes (iOS app) tableViewCell which previews songs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm creating an app which would provide the user with a list of audio files and let them sample a small piece of audio when they select the song (just like the iTunes iOS app).

I love the way the iTunes iOS App has implemented it (image attached); wherein I can click on a cell and the album cover flips over to show a progress indicator and a stop button. I can select a cell and the sample starts to play, and the moment I stop it, the progress indicator flips back over to show the album/song art.

[image: iTunes iOS music preview]

I'd like to create something like that for my app. Any suggestions on how I can go ahead with it.

Thanks a ton in advance! :D

**EDIT:** Based on Till's suggestion, I'm adding this edit. What I wish to get by asking this question is suggestions for the best approach to make the flip animation, showing a custom view in a UITableViewCell image space, possible. Currently, I'm not worried about playing the audio or displaying the progress of the playback. I simply need suggestions on the best approach to perform the flip animation and substitute the image with a custom UIView. :) Thanks again! :D

Comment: I would imagine you need to create this effect in a custom subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: This question, though nicely illustrated seems to be overly broad. At the moment I somehow suspect that you want someone to do your work and you simply intend to copy it. Make sure you try to ask very specific things - e.g. how to recognize if a user tapped on a cell within a UITableView, how to play a sound and monitor the playback progress, how to display an animated bitmap within a cell, ...

Comment: @Till: Hmm, I'll rephrase my question. I want suggestions on how I can go about it, so that I can write my own code. I do not wish to copy paste someone else's code. Although I'm relatively new to iOS land, I wish to write my own stuff regardless of whether it takes more time or not. Additionally, I'm not worried about how I can detect a tap and how to go about playing audio, since I know how to do it. The only thing I'm interested in knowing is how to go about performing the flip animation in a UITableViewCell image space. :)

Comment: @codeBearer ah, ok - understood. For such flip-animation, you would commonly use CoreAnimation. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928781/core-animation-flip-animation

Comment: Well, I had to go off and work on something else for some time. However, I resumed working on this today, and I used `[UIView transitionFromView:oldImageView toView:newCustomView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished){some code}];` However, this is flipping all the subviews of the cell. How do I flip only the imageView and the custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create it. I suggest making it as a custom tablecell. If you polish it well enought, you can put it on CodeCanyon and make it worth your while.

Also, I can recommend looking at the works on http://cocoacontrols.com/ - It might not have exactly this one, but it has many interesting controls and inspirations.

Comment: Thank you for that link! :) I will take a look into it. If I get this working, I'd be more than happy to put it up on CodeCanyon or make it public on GitHub! :) Again, really appreciate the link! :D

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what u looking for:

https://github.com/marshluca/AudioPlayer

You can also refer to some Sources :

https://github.com/lipka/LLACircularProgressView